# Populating table layout from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm populating TableLayout from Databases. i have created a method buildTable to fetch data from databases and create table rows dynamically, called that method in MainActivity onCreate method. Everything is fine there is no error but it didn't show the Table with data when i run the application.

**Here is my try Main Activity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText userName, Password ,salary, Address, name;
    private TableLayout t1;
    TestDatabaseAdapter testHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.salaryEditText);
        Address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchTextView);
       t1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

        testHelper = new TestDatabaseAdapter(this);
        BuildTable();

    }
    private void BuildTable() {
        Cursor mCur = testHelper.populateTable();
        Message.message(this, "Successfully inserted a row at "+mCur.getCount());
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int rows = mCur.getCount();
                    int cols = mCur.getColumnCount();

                    // outer for loop
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

                        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                                new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                                        (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

                        // inner for loop
                        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

                            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                            tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tv.setTextSize(18);
                            tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

                            tv.setText(mCur.getString(j));
                            row.addView(tv);

                        }
                        t1.addView(row);
                    }
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    }


    public void addUser(View view){

        String user = userName.getText().toString();
        String pass = Password.getText().toString();
        String sal = salary.getText().toString();
        String add = Address.getText().toString();

        long id = testHelper.insertData(user,pass,sal,add);
        if (id<0){
            Message.message(this, "Unsuccessful");
        }
        else {
            Message.message(this, "Successfully inserted a row at "+id);
        }
    }


    public void getUserDetails(View view){
        String data = testHelper.getAllData();
        Message.message(this, data);
    }


    public void getSingleUserDetails(View view){
        String s1 = name.getText().toString();

        if (!(s1.isEmpty())) {
            String sub1 = s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf(" "));
            String sub2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(" ")+1);

            String data = testHelper.getSingleUserDate(sub1,sub2);
            if (data.isEmpty()){
                Message.message(this, "No record found");
            }
            else {
                Message.message(this, data);
            }
        } else {
            Message.message(this, "Enter Some Text ");
        }
    }


    public void update(View view){
        String s1 = name.getText().toString();

        if (!(s1.isEmpty())) {
            String sub1 = s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf(" "));
            String sub2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(" ")+1);

            int data = testHelper.updateAddress(sub1, sub2);
            if (data<1){
                Message.message(this, "No record found");
            }
            else {
                Message.message(this, data+ " : Rows Successfully updated ");
            }
        } else {
            Message.message(this, "Enter Some Text ");
        }
    }

    public void delete(View view){
        String s1 = name.getText().toString();

        if (!(s1.isEmpty())) {
            String sub1 = s1.substring(0,s1.indexOf(" "));
            String sub2 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(" ")+1);

            int data = testHelper.deletebyName(sub1, sub2);
            if (data<1){
                Message.message(this, "No record found");
            }
            else {
                Message.message(this, data+ " : Rows Successfully deleted ");
            }
        } else {
            Message.message(this, "Enter Some Text ");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Here is my activity_main**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Linealayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/userNameTextView"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/PassWordTextView"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SalaryTextView"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/salaryEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/AddressTextView"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addressEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addUser"
            android:text="@string/AddUserButton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/detailsButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="BuildTable"
            android:text="Get User Details" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter Name of person" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="getSingleUserDetails"
            android:text="Get User Salary &amp; Address " />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Update"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="update" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="delete" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_table"
            android:background="#8cff9d2c"></TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**Class :** Message.java

```
public class Message {
    public static void message(Context context, String message){
        Toast.makeText(context , message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Class: TestDatabaseAdapter.java**

```
  public class TestDatabaseAdapter {

    TestHelper testHelper;

    public TestDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        testHelper = new TestHelper(context);
    }

    public long insertData(String name, String password, String salary, String Address) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = testHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_SALARY, salary);
        contentValues.put(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS, Address);

        long id = db.insert(testHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return id;
    }
    public Cursor populateTable(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = testHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ID, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_SALARY, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TestHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);


    return cursor;
    }
    public String getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = testHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        //select * from EmployeeTable
        String[] columns = {TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ID, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_SALARY, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TestHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int c1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ID);
            int c2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME);
            int c3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD);
            int c4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_SALARY);
            int c5 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS);

            int id = cursor.getInt(c1);
            String name = cursor.getString(c2);
            String pass = cursor.getString(c3);
            String salary = cursor.getString(c4);
            String address = cursor.getString(c5);

            buffer.append(id + " " + name + " " + pass + " " + salary + " " + address + "\n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public String getSingleUserDate(String searchName,String searchPass) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = testHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        //select salary & address from EmployeeTable where name = ? AND pass = ?
        String[] columns = {TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_SALARY, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS};
        String[] selectionArgs={searchName,searchPass};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TestHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME + " =? AND "+TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD+ " =?", selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         /*   int c1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ID);
            int c2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME);
            int c3 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD);*/
            int c4 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_SALARY);
            int c5 = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS);

        /*    int id = cursor.getInt(c1);
            String name = cursor.getString(c2);
            String pass = cursor.getString(c3);*/
            String salary = cursor.getString(c4);
            String address = cursor.getString(c5);

            buffer.append(/*id + " " + name + " " + pass + " " + */salary + " " + address + "\n");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public int updateAddress(String name, String newAdd){
        SQLiteDatabase db = testHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS, newAdd);
        String[] whereArgs ={name};
        int count = db.update(TestHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME + " =? ", whereArgs);
        return count;
    }

    public int deletebyName(String name,String pass){
        SQLiteDatabase db = testHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String[] whereArgs = {name,pass};
        int count = db.delete(TestHelper.TABLE_NAME, TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME+ "= ? AND "+ TestHelper.EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD+ " =? ",whereArgs);

        return count;
    }


    static class TestHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 17;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TestDB";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "EmployeeTable";
        static final String EMPLOYEE_ID = "_id";
        static final String EMPLOYEE_NAME = "Name";
        static final String EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD = "Password";
        static final String EMPLOYEE_SALARY = "Salary";
        static final String EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS = "Address";


        private Context context;

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + EMPLOYEE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + EMPLOYEE_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(255) , " + EMPLOYEE_SALARY + " INTEGER , " + EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS + " VARCHAR(255) );";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE_QUERY = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        public TestHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            Message.message(context, "Constructer Called");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY);
                Message.message(context, "onCreate Called");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Message.message(context, "" + e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_QUERY);
                Message.message(context, "onUpgrade Called");
                onCreate(db);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Message.message(context, "" + e);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: From where do you fetch your database?

Comment: @Faiyaz from Helper class . Created a method there to fetch data into a cursor i have checked with Logcat getting the data that is not the issue

Comment: Urrrm, a `ScrollView` containing a `LinearLayout` containing another `ScrollView` containing a `TableLayout` (which is also scrollable). Are you really sure you want to do that?

Comment: You should first of all take that TableLayout out of the ScrollView. TableLayout is also a scrollable view. Then why you added it inside two scrollviews?

Comment: Outer ScrollView is not for TableLayout its not the complete xml code but i try removing the inner ScrollView

Comment: Tried Removing the inner 'ScrollView' not working. Should i post the complete code?

Comment: @user2992655 : I'd suggest you create a very simple layout XML file which contains ONLY the `TableLayout` and test it that way. Once you get the `TableLayout` showing, then concentrate on making the overall layout more complex as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out i was using `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

So i just changed the Above Code to `TableRow.LayoutParams`

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
           TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And it worked like a charm.